# iOS :put the id type as string to print

Tags: ios, ios5

In android I can `Log("aa",""+Object)`,then the object can as string to print,it can help me understand the object and if object is int type, I am not to converter,so I want to do as the same as in iOS. for example: I want to print the id type as string at iOS as follows:

```
NSLog(@"#### %s",[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)]);
```

I want to print the return value of `[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)]` as string so that I can understand the `indexSetWithIndexesInRange` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `%@`, that's the format that prints `NSObject`'s `description` (cocoa's analog to Java's `toString`).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the object 'id', consider the following -

```
    print("#A>\(String(format: "%@", arguments: [self]))");
    print("#B>\(String(format: "%d", arguments: [self]))");
    print("#C>\(String(format: "%d", arguments: [self.hash]))");
    print("#D>\(String(format: "%d", arguments: [self.hashValue]))");
```

I get the following console output (for my example code in TimerCell.swift)-

```
    #A><MultiTimer.TimerCell: 0x7fa133806200; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 75); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa131d07080>>
    #B>864051712
    #C>864051712
    #D>864051712
```